# Disable removal of ASPX extension

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis

I created a C# application in Visual Studio which is hosted on IIS 7.5. Accessing the application's ASPX files directly results with an automatic removal of their extension (the pages are rendered correctly).

For example, when accessing the following URL:
http://www.example.com/contact.aspx

The following URL is returned from the server:
http://www.example.com/contact

I would like to configure the application so accessing an ASPX file with its extension will result with a returned URL containing the extension.

There is no `<rewrite>` tag in web.config.

Global.asax content:

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="WebSite2" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Optimization" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Routing" %>

<script runat="server">

    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }

</script>
```

RouteConfig.cs content:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Routing;
using Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls;

namespace WebSite2
{
    public static class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
            settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
            routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please post your `Global.asax` code or see if you have any `<rewrite>` tag in your `web.config`

Comment: Do you have any `RouteConfig.cs` coding performed?

Comment: comment out this line `routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);`

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`RouteConfig.cs` file defines how routing works in your web application.

Just remove the code related to `FriendlyUrlSettings` and it should work as you expected.

```
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
            settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
            routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);
        }
```